# cv::imshow over SSH x11 too slow. alternatives?

Tags: opencv, ros

I have an application processing live frames from a camera that then spits out the result frame with imshow. When running on the local machine it all runs smoothly.

However, I need to call this application over SSH and still see the video somehow(doesn't need to be over ssh). Currently the application just works over X11 forwarding, but the frame rates are abysmal and theres a huge delay.

Is there a better way to do this that would minimize lag and latency?

Comment: Are you networked over WiFi, or 100Mb/s Ethernet on Raspi 3 or GbE on Raspi4?

Comment: networked over WiFi, but 5Ghz

Comment: Have you watched the network throughput rate on your local machine? Have you tried JPEG-encoding frames and sending them via a socket to a receiver in your local machine that decodes and displays with `cv2.imshow()`?

Comment: What OS are you running on the host you `ssh` from, i.e. presumably your local desktop? What resolution images are you sending in terms of height in pixels by width in pixels? What is your framerate? Are your images RGB or grey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried several methods of improving the performance of OpenCV's `imshow()` over an `ssh` connection. I am using a Mac as my local dekstop and a Raspberry Pi4 as the remote machine that I `ssh` into and which is generating the images for display on my Mac.

### Disabling compression on the `ssh` connection

I tried using:

```
ssh -o 'Compression no' pi4
```

and that resulted in around 6-8% throughput improvement, so it is hardly likely to be enough.

### Using a lighter-weight encryption cipher

I read that `arcfour` uses less resources and allows you to achieve higher throughput. Unfortunately, I tried that and it is not available on Raspbian, nor are there any other lightweight ciphers, it seems. I used this command to check the available cipers on the Raspberry Pi:

```
ssh -Q cipher
```

### Run X11 display outside of the `ssh` tunnel

As I failed to find a way to improve the `ssh` throughput, I decided to send the X11 unencrypted, rather than through the `ssh` tunnel. That meant I ran the following on the Mac to allow the X server to listen for direct connections and also to tell it to allow remote hosts to use it:

```
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 nolisten_tcp -bool false
xhost +
```

Then I `ssh` into the Raspberry Pi **without** using `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y` and ran:

```
export DISPLAY=<MAC_IP_ADDRESS>:0
./opencvScript
```

That resulted in somewhat better performance, but it was still not ground-breaking.

---

I then decided to use **Redis** which is a very high performance, in-memory data-structure server. It is simple to install on a Mac or any other machine. It allows you to share atomic integers, strings, lists, hashes, queues, sets and ordered sets between any number of clients across a network. So, I simply JPEG-encode and send each frame of video from the Raspberry Pi to Redis and then pick the frames up on my Mac as fast as I can and display them. It works silky-smooth and does 256 frames of 640x480 colour video in around 3 seconds, so 80 fps.

So here is the `DisplayServer` I run on my Mac. It just grabs the latest image as fast as it can and displays it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ImageTransferService
import numpy as np
import cv2

if __name__ == "__main__":

    host = '0.0.0.0'
    src = ImageTransferService.ImageTransferService(host)

    # Check Redis is running 
    print(src.ping())

    while True:
        im = src.receiveImage()
        cv2.imshow('Image',im)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Here is the code I run on the Raspberry Pi that sends images:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import ImageTransferService

if __name__ == "__main__":

    host = '192.168.0.8'
    RemoteDisplay = ImageTransferService.ImageTransferService(host)

    # Check remote display is up
    print(RemoteDisplay.ping())

    # Create BGR image
    w, h = 640, 480
    im = np.zeros((h,w,3),dtype=np.uint8)

    for c in range(256):
        im[:,:,0] = c
        RemoteDisplay.sendImage(im)
```

And here is the glue code that hides Redis and provides a way to send, receive and buffer images:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import redis
import cv2
import numpy as np

class ImageTransferService:
    def __init__(self, host='localhost', port=6379):
        self.port = port
        self.host = host
        self.conn = redis.Redis(host,port)
        self.frameNum = 0

    def ping(self):
        return self.conn.ping()

    def sendImage(self,im, name='latest', Q=75):
        _, JPEG = cv2.imencode(".JPG", im, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), Q])
        myDict = { 'frameNum': self.frameNum, 'Data':JPEG.tobytes() }
        self.conn.hmset(name, myDict)
        self.frameNum += 1

    def receiveImage(self,name='latest'):
        myDict  = self.conn.hgetall(name)
        Data = myDict.get(b'Data')
        im = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(Data,dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        return im
```

As Redis has many bindings, you can access the frames of data and look into Redis or write stuff into Redis from PHP, Python, C/C++, PHP or even the command-line. So, the line below, when run in the shell, will grab the latest frame of your video, for example:

```
redis-cli hgetall latest
```

Here is a little video of the code in action, it simply increments the Blue channel from 0 through 255 to produce 255 frames. As you see, it goes from the Raspberry Pi (in the lower Terminal window) to the Mac (in the upper Terminal window running the DisplayServer code) in around 3s.

[image]

---

I also did a version using sockets to transfer the JPEG-encoded images and that was nearly as fast but somewhat uglier, and also less flexible and unbuffered and also not as controllable or debuggable from outside like Redis is.

**Keywords**: Raspberry Pi, OpenCV, display, remote display, X11, tunnel, ssh, DISPLAY, Redis, buffer, image, image processing, performance, XQuartz, listen, incoming, connections.