# Streaming images in realtime via OpenCV (C++) in a local network

Tags: c++, opencv

first of all a few key facts of my project:

- one computer (processes the images in OpenCV, C++) has to offer images to
  three other computers in a local network in realtime
- we already set up a NGINX Media Server + hotspot on a Raspberry Pi
  (works fine)
- the three clients should be able to easily access the images (see the example
  code below)

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

  using namespace cv;
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
  const string url = "rtmp://192.168.4.1/myapp/mystream";

  cv::VideoCapture capture(url);

  if (!capture.isOpened())
  {
      cout << "No data!" << endl;
  }

  namedWindow("Stream", WINDOW_NORMAL);
  resizeWindow("Image", 600, 600);

  Mat frame;

  while (1) 
  {
      if (!capture.read(frame)) 
      {
          cout << "No data!" << endl;
      }
      imshow("Stream", frame);

      waitKey(30);
  }
  }
  ```

**Issues:**

- no idea how to stream directly from the C++ program to NGINX via
  ffmpeg
- we tried it via OBS, but we experienced a bad latency of more than 4
  seconds..

Is it a wrong approach in general or are there some secret libraries available? 
Another option is a C++ socket system - would it be more suitable?

Comment: I think you won't get better timing then with rtmp if you are using ethernet

Comment: Unfortunately, library and software recommendations are off-topic for stackoverflow.com

Comment: I would consider throwing the images into Redis (probably as JPEGs) and letting any clients help themselves... https://stackoverflow.com/a/57910157/2836621

Answer (score 0):

I think NGINX is a good solution for your problem. Easy to setup and use + normally low delay compared to others.
In your code, I would recommend to change the

```
waitKey(30);
```

to

```
waitKey(5);
```

to reduce input buffer.

OBS should be one of the fastest ways to setup a stream. You can try to switch "tune" in advanced output options to "zerolatency".
Also make sure that you have stream delay disabled in Advanced Options!