# shared memory between c++ and python

Tags: python, c++, sockets, shared-memory

I'm trying to connect c++(server) and python(client) using socket and want to send share data using shared memory also message sending. Data in the formate of CSV file which is created by c++.

Comment: It's not clear what is the problem you have.

Comment: Are you sure that shared memory is what you want? Perhaps you should look at serialization instead?

Comment: Did you notice that you have answers to your question? It would be customary, and appreciated, if you gave some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that very simply, fast and even across networks with **Redis**, which has bindings for C/C++. Python, Ruby, `bash` and so on. It is a very fast, light-weight, *"in-memory"* data-structure server that can serve integers, strings, lists, queues, FIFOs, sets, atomic integers, hashes, ordered sets etc. It can also run on **Linux**, **macOS** and **Windows**, in client or server form, without worrying about the differences in shared memory and sockets between those platforms.

The `bash` CLI (command-line interface) makes it very simple to debug what's going on in your code and also to inject test data.

So, for example, you could use a **Redis** [hash](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro) to represent your data - I am just using the Terminal here to connect to the localhost, but it could be on any machine:

```
redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1

127.0.0.1:6379> hmset day:1 1 s 2 e 3 i 4 r
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> hmset day:5 1 e 2 i 3 r 4 r
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall day:5
1) "1"
2) "e"
3) "2"
4) "i"
5) "3"
6) "r"
7) "4"
8) "r"
127.0.0.1:6379> hmget day:5 4
1) "r"
```

---

Non-interactive version:

```
redis-cli --raw hmget day:5 2
i
```

---

Retrieve the `day1` values with Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import redis

# Redis connection
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost')

# Retrieve our hash from Redis
day1 = r.hgetall("day:1")

print(day1)
```

**Sample Output**

```
{b'1': b's', b'2': b'e', b'3': b'i', b'4': b'r'}
```

---

Examples of C/C++ and Python bindings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60976666/2836621).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows you can try Memurai. It's a really fast-data store. It works like a charm