# how to set shared memory between python and c++ in linux and osx

Tags: python, c++, shared-memory, mmap

I was able to share memory on windows simply using winapi in cpp and mmap.mmap in python. just match "name".

And I was able to set the name of the shared memory using `<boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>` on mac.

But python's `mmap`.[mmap()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html#:%7E:text=fileno%2C%20and%20returns%20a-,mmap,-object.%20If%20length) didn't work. Even in the official documentation the parameters were different. It didn't have a parameter to set a name for.

So I gave up and decided to use `<sys/ipc.h>`.

It was able to communicate with python using the key, but `write()` to `sysv_ipc` in python gives the following error:

> ValueError: Attempt to write past end of memory segment

- python code

```py
shm = sysv_ipc.SharedMemory(777)
if shm:
    offset = 0
    for idx in range(0, 21):
        shm.write(struct.pack(
            'f', hand_landmarks.landmark[idx].x), offset)
        offset += 4
        shm.write(struct.pack(
            'f', hand_landmarks.landmark[idx].y), offset)
        offset += 4
        shm.write(struct.pack(
            'f', hand_landmarks.landmark[idx].z), offset)
        offset += 4
```

- c++ code

```cpp
shmid = shmget(777, 512, IPC_CREAT | 0666)
shared_memory = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0)
fptr = reinterpret_cast<float *>(shared_memory);
for (int i = 0; i < 63; i += 3)
{
    std::cout << fptr[i] << " " << fptr[i + 1] << " " << fptr[i + 2] << "\n";
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you considered using **Redis** - it is very lightweight, very fast, very easy and works across lots of platforms and languages (including the command-line which makes it very simple to inject test data or monitor your app)- you could try it out without installation just using `dockerhub`.

Comment: @Mark Setchell Looking at it, it seems like a good to change it!

Comment: You could have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/66456923/2836621 or here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58521903/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues is that `shmget` second parameters in in bits, not bytes.

So the correct way to write the code is:

```cpp
shmid = shmget(777, 512 * 8, IPC_CREAT | 0666)
```